# How do i install the latest version of Ruby on Mac?

Tags: ruby, macos, installation, rubygems

After installing Ruby 2.0, I try and run my .rb file, and get this error:

```
/Users/Andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require': cannot load such file -- ruby-box (LoadError)
    from /Users/Andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from box.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

My code:

```
require "rubygems"
require "ruby-box"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you installed ruby-box for your new Ruby? Try running this, and trying again:

```
gem install ruby-box
```

Also note that `require "rubygems"` is useless and redundant (the interpreter deals with all this for you) in Ruby 1.9 and onwards.

Comment: Thanks. In future, is there a more efficient way of moving all my RubyGems over to the latest version?

Comment: @Andrew: Depends. Are you moving for an RVM version to RVM version, or from system Ruby to RVM?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [bundler](http://bundler.io/) to manage your dependencies even if it is a small project. It provides install and update tools to help mitigate these exact problems. For example, you could update all your dependencies with one command:

```
bundle update
```

The time invested learning bundler will quickly pay for itself :D